# Combine sequential dataframes in list with the same number of columns (From PDF where they were split by page breaks)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tabula

After reading a PDF with Tabula, I have some dataframes that were split because they spanned multiple pages.  I want to concatenate them and remove the header row so that I restore the full table.  I imagine the number of tables will change per document, so this seems like it should cover any scenario where tables get split up.

I know I want a for loop to go through the list and check if the next dataframe has the same number of columns.  If so, the two should be concatenated.  Manually concatenating (using print(pd.concat([df_list[12],df_list[13],df_list[14]]))) works, so it's just a matter of figuring out how to write this.

Here's my approximation of what it should be:

```
import pandas as pd
import tabula

df_list=read_pdf("test.pdf",multiple_tables=True,lattice=True,pages='all',encoding='utf-8',spreadsheet=True)

for i in df_list:
    if i.shape[1] = (i+1).shape[1]:
        pd.concat([i,(i+1)])
```

I get the error "TypeError: Could not operate 1 with block values must be str, not int" but I'm not sure what I'm doing with this for loop.

Comment: In this case, I think you're mixing iteration over the items in the list, and the indices of the list. `for i in df_list` means that `i` is a df, but `(i+1).shape[1]` implies that `i` should be the index instead. As it stands, you're checking whether `df` and `df+1` (adding 1 to all values in the dataframe) are the same size

Answer (score 0):

The type of `i` in your loop appears to be in conflict with the type of `1` (which is `int`) in the expression `i+1`. You don't show the creation of `df_list` in the posted code, but my guess would be that it is `str`, hence the `TypeError`: you are trying to combine an int (`1`) with a string (`i`) using the `+` operator.

Comment: It should have been df_list instead of df.  I've fixed that mistake.  I see what you're saying, though.  I would have to enumerate this list, then?

Comment: If `read_pdf` returns an iterable, yes, I think something like `for i, df in enumerate(df_list)...` would work.